# Android massive database creation

Tags: java, android, sql, database, performance

So guys, this is a big one
I'm currently working on an App which involves a big database creation.
Basicalls what it does is scanning the entire device for any kind of media file and adds it to the database (filtered by certain file extensions).
The way it currently does that is scanning through the device's folders with a recursive function, and every time it finds a file that is actually a file and not a directory AND matches the file extensions I picked it adds the file's path to a previously created ArrayList containing only strings.
This is implemented in an AsyncTask so it's done in the background.
As soon as that task finishes it passes the ArrayList on to another AsyncTask that is responsible for adding those files to the database. Out of simplicity resons I only took the file's path, its name and the title that is stored in its tags for every entry (simple sqlite stuff) and displayed the titles in a ListView in another activity over cursor adapters and so on (which isnt really an issue in my case).
Right now it workes pretty well, doesn't crash or return anything bad (I'm testing on a OnePlus One right now).
BUT I have a really big music library on my phone (around 5400 songs) which is nearly filling my entire storage. And out of some unknown reason to me, the scanning task i mentioned (with the ArrayList) stops at around 3000 files and passes the ArrayList on to the second task, which is obviously not what I'm aming at to have.
My guess is that there might be a big performance issue and using an ArrayList is not the best way to approach this. It might work with a number of files that is under 3000 but higher than that is also necessary...
So what would you guys suggest? Does my approach lack something or do I have to try something completely different?

Comment: Conceptually speaking, you can repeat both the tasks while taking a fixed number of files (500 for example).

Comment: I think rather than storing in list you can save music path to the Database table than use .... this link to retrieve https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-list-view-from-database-with-cursor-adapter/

Comment: but then i'd have the problem of picking up where i left, sure i can save the path for later, but then i couldnt start the recursive function from there in order to get back to the root

Comment: Imagine you have a loop in function `abc()` which is traversing the file system. add a counter in the loop and when your counter reaches 500, call a function for example `xyz()` and pass your array list to this function. The `xyz` function will pass this arraylist to the other async task and execute it. Once the you get the control back to the `abc` function from `xyz`, reset your counter and continue the traversing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need scan your folders (and, probably, creating database of media files too), you can just use [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) class

> The Media provider contains meta data for all available media on both internal and external storage devices.

For example, this piece of code will return all available audio playlists

```
private List<Playlist> getPlayListsList(){
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] columns = { _ID, NAME };
    Cursor playLists = resolver.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);

    List<Playlist> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (playLists == null) {
        return result;
    }

    Cursor cursor;
    for (boolean hasItem = playLists.moveToFirst(); hasItem; hasItem = playLists.moveToNext()) {
        long id = playLists.getLong(playLists.getColumnIndex(_ID));
        String name = playLists.getString(playLists.getColumnIndex(NAME));

        cursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", id),
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ARTIST,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER}, null, null, null
        );

        int songsCount = cursor.getCount();

        result.add( new Playlist(
                id,
                name,
                songsCount));
        cursor.close();
    }
    playLists.close();
    return result;
}
```